# PHP imagick_writeImage can't write image

Tags: php, imagick

I need to convert `.dcom` pictures into `.jpg` picture for printing, So I have path to .dcom files in my DB, but I have trouble with writing .jpg image into folder...
Here is the code how I am trying to save `.jpg` picture

```
$test = imagick_readimage('V:\PACS\DCM\USMFD3\2014\02\04\1.2.840.113663.1500.1.295897643.3.1.20140204.74935.437');
imagick_writeimage($test, 'img\1.2.840.113663.1500.1.295897643.3.1.20140204.74935.437.jpg')
```

but when I am trying to `var_dump(imagick_writeimage($test, 'img\1.2.840.113663.1500.1.295897643.3.1.20140204.74935.437.jpg'));` I get `bool(false)`

**UPDATE1:** here is `var_dump` of `$test` - `resource(1) of type (imagick handle)`

So what I am doing wrong?

P.S If you need more code to see, please write a coment, and I will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only  a guess, but i think you web server is not allowed to write to there.
Are you sure that the readimage works?

Your path V looking like a windows mapped network drive.
Maybe you webserver-process doesn't have that mapped drive.

I could be also a problem with the relative path in writeimage.
This could be: \img.
Normally "c:\programm files*" where no write access is allowed.

Comment: yes, I have permissions for writing into this directory, I tryed write simple .txt fit file_put_contents, and it was there after executing script, but I will try to change oath for writing

update: I changed writing path to `\img\image.jpg`, but it doesnot helps=(

Comment: You tried it with the webserver-process-account? Each user (also system) has an own profile in windows. if a drive is mapped to your personal (admin)-account, others won't see that drive. May people forget that the webserver runs in a own account.